# What is the point of .pipe(map())

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am just looking in to this example https://github.com/arjunyel/angular-apollo-example/blob/master/frontend/src/app/app.component.ts#L28

It has this code:

```
 this.tweets = this.tweetsGQL
      .watch()
      .valueChanges.pipe(map(tweets => tweets.data));
```

Just wondering how the `this.tweets` gets the value assigned? Is it something to do with `.pipe(map())` can you give some details on that?

Comment: `.pipe(map(()` is used to transform the value that's emitted by the observable, so instead of emitting the `tweets` object, it emits the `tweets.data`. The `this.tweets` variable holds an `Observable` though, not the actual data.

Comment: The value won't be assigned directly to `this.tweets`. You'll have to `subscribe` to this.tweets to get the tweets data.

All the `.pipe(map())` is doing is, transforming the actual data you get from the API and returning the `data` property of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular to show data in a *ngFor we can take two aproachs:

Show an observable using async. generally we use a convention that an observable variable begins by $

```
<div *ngFor="let tweet of ($tweets | async)?.tweets">
  ....
</div>
//In this case we use
this.$tweets=this.tweetsGQL
      .watch()
      .valueChanges.pipe(map(res=> res.data));
```

Show an array

```
<div *ngFor="let tweet of tweets.tweets">
  ....
</div>
//In this case we must subscribe -and not equal the observable to anything
this.tweetsGQL
      .watch()
      .valueChanges.pipe(map(res=> res.data))
      .subscribe(res=>this.tweets=res);
```

About "map(tweets=>twees.data)". The observable can return anything. In this case return an object like

```
{data:tweets:[....],otherProperty:value}
```

We can map (transform) the response so the observable only return the "property" data. Not the whole object

```
map(res=>res.data)
//the for must be over tweets.tweets *ngFor="let tweet of tweets.tweets"
```

even we can map the response so the observable return data.tweets

```
map(res=>res.data.tweets)
//the for must be over tweets *ngFor="let tweet of tweets"
```

NOTE:I change the response using the variable "res" to avoid confusions

Answer (score -1):

As others said `this.tweets` hold only the observable not the actual data, you have to subscribe the observable to get the actual data.

```
.pipe(map(tweets => tweets.data))
```

It is short hand of `.pipe(map(tweets => { return  tweets.data}))`. So it implicitly returning the tweets.data as a observable to the `this.tweets`.